# Ordering polynomials in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm researching material on polynomial vector spaces and notice almost all sources use ascending order, as in...

$a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots + a_nx^n$ and $W = \{1+x, -1+2x+x^2, 4x-x^2\}$

Generally, descending order, $W = \{x+1, x^2+2x-1, -x^2+4x\}$, seems much more intuitive for me, especially once you start working in with matrices.

Is there a good reason for using ascending order or does it not really matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very natural reason to write them in ascending order is to allow a very natural generalization to series.

You definitely don't want to write $a_0 +a_1 x + a_2 x^2+ a_3 x^3 + \cdots$ beginning by the last term :D

Answer (score 2):

Think about this problem:

1. Give a basis of third-degree polynomial.
2. Only adding an element to the previous result, give a basis of fourth-degree polynomials.

If you plan to build progressively higher and higher order polynomial spaces, it seems logical to consider polynomials in increasing degree order.

Another example would be building more and more accurate Taylor approximations.

Beyond that intuition, there is no formal difference and polynomials are exactly the same regardless how they are written.